# Mod rewrite domains.com/some-keywords

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have urls like this:
domains.com/?page=some-keywords

I want to change to:
domains.com/some-keywords

I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)(/?)$ /?page=$1 [L]
```

And

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?page=$1 [L]
```

But this is not working, I have 5xx errors. Its working only when I put some more in rules. for example

```
RewriteRule ^123,([^/]*)(/?)$ /?page=$1 [L]
```

There is possible to have that urls on apache?
from domains.com/?page=some-keywords
to domains.com/some-keywords

Answer (score 0):

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "^page=(.*)"
  RewriteRule ^/$ /%1 [QSD,R]
```

RewriteCond directive will detect whether a query string parameter called page exists.

RewriteRule directive will map the URL from "/" to "/{value-of-page-parameter}".

This is achieved by using "%1" token. The token "%1" contains the value captured by "(.*)" from RewriteCond.

QSD flag is used to discard the original query string.

R flag is used to redirect the old URL to the new URL.